# How to manually trim traceback from exception without using sys.tracebacklimit?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, try-catch, traceback

Example:

```py
>>> def f(): g()
... 
>>> def g(): h()
... 
>>> def h(): raise Exception
... 
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in g
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in h
Exception
>>>
```

What I want is this:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.tracebacklimit = 1
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in h
Exception
>>>
```

But I am unable to use `sys.tracebacklimit` in my case. Is there an alternative way to manually trim the traceback before raising the exception?

```py
try:
    f()
except Exception as e:
    # trim traceback here
    raise
```

What I found out so far:

> Special writable attribute: tb_next is the next level in the stack trace (towards the frame where the exception occurred), or None if there is no next level.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#traceback-objects

So this is doing the opposite of what I want by trimming the wrong end of the traceback:

```py
>>> try:
...     f()
... except Exception as e:
...     e.__traceback__.tb_next = None
...     raise
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
Exception
>>>
```

Also, it is possible to simply replace exception `e` with another exception of the desired traceback (notice 3x `.tb_next` to skip the traceback steps in `<module>`, `f` and `g`). However, because we are not using a "bare" `raise` (i.e. not raising the "original" exception), that `raise` adds itself (as a traceback step in `<module>`) to the traceback:

```
>>> try:
...     f()
... except Exception as e:
...     raise e.with_traceback(e.__traceback__.tb_next.tb_next.tb_next)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in h
Exception
>>>
```